# Jekyll github site- posts not building

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll, travis-ci, github-pages

We are trying to add new posts to our Jekyll site, but for some reason, they are not building/ appearing on the live site. Can anyone tell what the problem is? The four most recent posts are the ones that won't build.

Also, we used to have Travis CI set up to help us troubleshoot build errors, but it randomly stopped working- has that happened to anyone else? Anyone know how to get that working again?

Here is the site:
http://outercoast.org/news.html

Here is the repo:
https://github.com/javbotero/Outer-Coast/tree/master/_posts

Comment: Travis CI have recently changed there pricing model: https://blog.travis-ci.com/2020-11-02-travis-ci-new-billing. Most probably this is your reason for the Travis issue.

Comment: As for your issue, you should go in the setting of your repo: https://github.com/javbotero/Outer-Coast/settings, there, somewhere down the page, there is a status of how your GitHub page last build, this might give you extra information